# How do I place the blog portion of wordpress in a subdirectory, while keeping Pages at the root?

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to Wordpress, and I'm using it as a general CMS for the first time. It's a simple site with a few pages, and also a blog. The blog has the same theme as the rest of the site.

In any case, I'd like the blog home page to be at /blog, and the Pages at /{page-slug}, and a Page is assigned to the root of the site. What's the best way to basically put a standard Wordpress blog home at /blog/? I'd prefer it if all blog stuff were based at /blog (e.g. "/blog/2009/10/%postname%", "/blog/categories/news", etc.), but it's not an absolute necessity.

Will I need to do multiple Wordpress installs to support this natively? What limitations might I run into?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'd written out the question when I found the answer, so I thought I'd finish it for posterity. The answer is [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Your_Blog_Appear_in_a_Non-Root_Folder).

Permalink structure apparently doesn't affect Pages, which was my confusion. Wordpress will  always put Pages at /{page_slug}/. If you want to move the whole site, including Pages to a subdirectory, you can use the Blog address (URL) field under Settings/General.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

[WordPress Codex: Creating a Static Front Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)

WordPress allows you to make a 'front' page appear at `/` and shove your blog to a fake subdir, like `/blog/` — Your other pages will still be at `/your-page/`

Comment: As of this writing (Wordpress version 3.9.1), this is the better answer.